# Having two or multiple plot legend lines next to a single string

Tags: plotting, legending

This question showed up as a gentleman asked on reddit.
Had a quick jab at it and thought might be useful.
The request was to have legends for a plot where each legend mark represents two traces on the plot.

[image: Requested output for a legend]

Answer (score 3):

```
k = {6, 4, 2};
lbls = Row[{Subscript["N", "B"] , #}, " = "] & /@ k;
cols = {Red, Orange, Black};
```

You can use the option `LegendLayout` as follows:

```
linesperlabel = 2;
labels = Flatten[Thread[{lbls, ##& @@ ConstantArray[SpanFromAbove, linesperlabel - 1]}]];
plotstyles = Flatten[{#, Directive[#, Dashed]} & /@ cols];

LineLegend[plotstyles, labels, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"], 
 LegendLayout -> (Grid[Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], labels}], 
     Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
     Spacings -> {1, {Prepend[ConstantArray[0, linesperlabel - 1], 1]}}] &)]
```

[image]

```
functions = k[[#]] Sin[k[[#]] x + b] /. {b -> Range[linesperlabel]} & /@  Range @ 3;

Plot[Evaluate @ functions, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
 PlotStyle -> plotstyles, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16], 
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False}, ImageSize -> 450, 
 PlotRange -> {-8, 8}, 
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Automatic, labels, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 10}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"],
   LegendLayout -> (Grid[Transpose[{#[[All, 1]], labels}],
      Alignment -> {Center, Center}, 
      Spacings -> {1, {Prepend[ConstantArray[0, linesperlabel - 1], 1]}}] &)]]
```

[image]

Use

```
linesperlabel = 3;
labels = Flatten[Thread[{lbls, ## & @@ ConstantArray[SpanFromAbove, linesperlabel - 1]}]];
plotstyles = Flatten[{#, Directive[#, Dashed], Directive[#, Dotted]} & /@ cols];
functions = k[[#]] Sin[k[[#]] x + b] /. {b -> Range[linesperlabel]} & /@ Range@3;
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a built-in method within LineLegend or any other legend function to allow multiple lines. It seems that the fastest way forward is to have this created via Graphics, and then introduced in the plot as an inset using the Epilog option

```
sep = 0.05; (* separation between the two lines *)
size = 0.11; (* thickness of the legends *)

cols = {Red, Orange, Black}; (* colours of choice *)
 pix2mm = 72/25.4; (* pixel to mm conversion *)

(* creates two lines with a given colour, thickness and size. The \
second line is translated vertically
by the variable sep *)
legends = 
  Show[{Graphics[{#, Thickness[size], Line[{{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0}}}]}, 
       ImageSize -> 8*pix2mm],
      Graphics[{#, Dashed, Thickness[size], 
        Line[{{{0, -sep}, {0.1, -sep}}}]}, 
       ImageSize -> 8*pix2mm]}] & /@ cols;
(* creating the string associated with each 'legend' *)
vals = Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(N\), \(B\)]\) = " <> ToString[#], 
     Black, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] & /@ {6, 4, 0};

(* Assembling the two  using Grid *)
Grid[{legends[[#]], vals[[#]]} & /@ Range@3, Spacings -> {1, 2}]
```

Where the output looks like:

[image]

Introducing this into a plot hastily, but could easily be done using Inset, Placed, Legended,Graphics or Grid.
Here the example I am showing is that I have a variety of frequencies (and amplitudes), with a small offset:

```
Plot[ Evaluate[
  k[[#]] Sin[ k[[#]] x + b] /. {b -> {1, 2}} & /@ Range@3], {x, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]},
 PlotStyle -> 
  Flatten[{{cols[[#]]}, {cols[[#]], Dashed}} & /@ Range@3, 1],
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, 16],
 Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
 ImageSize -> 450, PlotRange -> {-8, 8},
 PlotLegends -> lgs]
```

[image]